# What are these weird IP addresses?

Tags: internet, internet-connection

As you can see in these tracerts, there are 3 weird IP address in there.

After that there are my ISP IP addresses and things.

What does this mean? Is there something between me and my ISP?

I'm not using a private network nor a Wi-Fi.

```
C:\>tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [200.40.172.38]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2    50 ms    49 ms    49 ms  172.28.0.9
  3    59 ms    59 ms    59 ms  172.28.0.14
  4    58 ms    50 ms    50 ms  172.28.0.17
  5    59 ms    49 ms    50 ms  ibb2uni4-be3.antel.net.uy [200.40.162.74]
  6    65 ms    59 ms    50 ms  ibb2agu4-bvi100.antel.net.uy [200.40.172.1]
  7    50 ms    50 ms    49 ms  r200-40-172-38.static.adinet.com.uy [200.40.172.
38]

Trace complete.

C:\>tracert www.wikpedia.org

Tracing route to www.wikpedia.org [208.80.154.224]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2   380 ms   359 ms   369 ms  172.28.0.9
  3   289 ms   458 ms   399 ms  172.28.0.14
  4   278 ms   329 ms   369 ms  172.28.0.17
  5   110 ms    49 ms    80 ms  r200-40-162-72.static.adinet.com.uy [200.40.162.
72]
  6    48 ms    49 ms    69 ms  cbb2une1-be150.antel.net.uy [200.40.162.5]
  7    48 ms    49 ms    60 ms  ibe2uni1-be150.antel.net.uy [200.40.162.6]
  8   190 ms   210 ms   199 ms  ibr2nap4-0-2-1-0.antel.net.uy [200.40.16.178]
  9   187 ms   189 ms   209 ms  te0-0-0-8.ccr21.mia03.atlas.cogentco.com [38.104
.95.245]
 10   219 ms   210 ms   219 ms  mai-b1-link.telia.net [213.248.75.1]
 11   208 ms   231 ms   218 ms  mai-b1-link.telia.net [62.115.112.166]
 12   207 ms   219 ms   210 ms  ash-bb3-link.telia.net [62.115.141.119]
 13   230 ms   239 ms   239 ms  ash-b1-link.telia.net [62.115.113.209]
 14   218 ms   239 ms   209 ms  wikimedia-ic-308845-ash-b2.c.telia.net [80.239.1
32.226]
 15   208 ms   209 ms   210 ms  text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org [208.80.154.224]

Trace complete.
```

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addresses you're seeing are called private addresses and since you believe you're "directly connected" and not within a private network of your own then they will form part of your ISP's network.

There are 3 ranges defined in the standard [RFC1918 - Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) and the addresses you're seeing fall into the 172.16/12 range (172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x).  You may be familiar with the 192.168/16 and the 10/24 address range and this is used in a similar way.

Note that the standard says *Private* and the point is merely that those addresses are not accessible from outside networks.  Nothing more, nothing less.

There are a handful of ways your ISP could be using them - Network Address Translation is a common usage, where many customers share a handful of IP addresses just like a home router shares one address with the devices inside the network.  But that is not the only one as they could be using them for router addressing internally, which makes it easy to stop anything from outside their network talking directly to one of their routers.

The addresses are not an indication of a problem, merely evidence of where your data is going within your provider's network.  The easiest way to know for sure is to ask them and one sign of a good ISP is that you'll get a decent and honest answer pretty quickly.

Comment: You write "Network Address Translation" <-- I'm no expert, but with NAT isn't the address replaced.. So the private address shouldn't appear on the Internet?

Comment: In NAT the address is hidden *from the outside world*, not endpoints on the same network.  But it doesn't have to be hidden and if I as the ISP wanted to route traffic from a gateway (with a public IP) through a private range to my end-user's public IP then it can be done without NAT and the routing will work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

They're private addresses. If you have some arrangement with whoever operates these devices that says they'll return real IPs to you, they're violating that arrangement and you should talk to them. If not, you have no right to expect useful information, especially given the shortage of IPv4 addresses. It doesn't make much sense for them to assign each interface unique, public IPv4 addresses just to make it easier for random people to traceroute across their backbone.

It looks like your traffic takes a few hops on your ISP's internal network before it reaches the Internet. And it looks like your ISP uses private IP addresses for interfaces on those internal devices.

Your ISP has a tradeoff to make. Each of these devices likely has at least one public IPv4 IP address, but not one for each interface. If they source the ICMP reply from the public interface, the IP address would like nice, but they wouldn't know which interface was involved. That would make things look nicer for you, but that would make troubleshooting harder for them. So instead they use the interface address as the source. This looks uglier for you, but it gives them more useful information when they traceroute.

Why do you care? Are you trying to troubleshoot their network?

Comment: Not sure if I agree with the last paragraph. It is _good_ to be curious about how things work and why they work. Many people would have become good engineers/admins/devs if they hadn't been repeatedly told "don't worry your pretty little head about it".

Comment: @grawity If the answer is "I care because I'm curious" that's fine. The point is that it's not something a person should ordinarily care about. The reason I think it's worth mentioning is that ISPs get a lot of annoying, time-wasting complaints about people who have no idea how to read a traceroute or understand a ping reply who complain that they think something is wrong or suspicious.

Comment: There is no guarantee that just because they're using the private address space that they're violating any kind of agreement.

Comment: @JamesSnell I agree. That's why I say "**If** you have some arrangement".